# Read word file content (image and text) with formatting information

Tags: c#, ms-word, richtextbox, office-interop, rtf

I want to convert the complex word document (which includes both text and images) into RTF text preserving formatting information. Sample image of document content is as shown below

[image]

How I can read this information as RTF text so that I can perfectly preserve the formatting and image location information. I tried to read word file using RichTextbox's LoadFile function but it doesn't preserve the formatting & image location information.

Looking forward to receive some suggestions to maintain the formatting and image location information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply save the document in the RTF format...

Comment: I tried that. I saved the document as rtf file and then I opened the file in notepad. In notepad, it did show me the RTF text but it didn't preserve the image location information.

Comment: Welcome to so @macropod. Big fan from msofficeforums.

Comment: @user2185592: in which format you need image location information. coordinates or inline?

Comment: I need to preserve the image location inline e.g. in image I have provided image is in center. But in some cases it could be on right side or left side. 
Upon converting to RTF this image location information is lost and I always get the image above the text